# Executing method with exec()

Tags: php, oop, execute

Is it efficient and/or possible to use `exec();` with a method of the same class?  Instead of executing a file with an `$argv` array, I'd like to pass variables to a method and execute it within another method:

```
class Foo{

    private function bar($table, $column, $id){
        //SQL 
    }

    public function bar_exec($table, $column, $id){
        exec($this->bar($table, $column, $id)); //this is most likely wrong
    }
}
```

The reasoning behind this is I have a method that chews through my database and takes quite a few arguments which in turn takes about a minute to finish, so I need to run it in the background whenever a form is submitted.  What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you spin up another PHP process, you also get a clean environment which has no knowledge of your current objects, call stack, or anything.  You have to treat it entirely separately.  The answer to your question is no.  You cannot spin up another process for just some method call.  You need to write a script that instantiates a new object and calls that method.

Comment: Understood, thanks.  I was also thinking about scheduling a cron job but that seems like overkill for a single method that is only running once after form submission, I'm not even sure if that's possible.